# LinkedList Read One by one

Tags: delphi

I am using simplelinkedlist. Here: (https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/generic-linked-lists-redux/)

I want to read all list one by one. But i couldnt find any option for this.

Here is my codes :

```
function TKduCache.addJPIPResponseData(jRes: TJPIPResponse): Boolean;
var
  data : TJPIPDataSegment;
begin
  data:= jRes.readLinkedList;
  while (data <> nil) and (not data.isEOR) do
  begin
    addDataSegment(data);
    data:= jRes.readLinkedList
  end;
  Result:= jRes.isResponseComplete;
end;
```

And readLinkedList method :

```
function TJPIPResponse.removeJpipDataSegment: TJPIPDataSegment;
begin
  Result:= TJPIPDataSegment(jpipDataList.First.Value);
end;
```

**SimpleLinkedList** can be read like;

- jpipDataList.First.Value
- jpipDataList.First.Next.Value
- jpipDataList.First.Next.Next.Value

**.
.
.**

how should i create my algorithm to read like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked list class you refer to has an enumerator. So you can do this:

```
var
  List: TSimpleLinkedList<Integer>;
  Item: Integer;
....
// create and populate List
for Item in List do
  DoSomething(Item);
```

Alternatively, you can use a classic `while` loop to iterate over the list:

```
var
  List: TSimpleLinkedList<Integer>;
  Node: TSimpleLinkedList<Integer>.TNode;
....
// create and populate List
Node := List.First;
while Assigned(Node) do
begin
  DoSomething(Node.Value);
  Node := Node.Next;
end;
```